# R - test if first occurrence of string1 is followed by string2

Tags: r, contains

I have an R string, with the format

```
s = `"[some letters and numbers]_[a number]_[more numbers, letters, punctuation, etc, anything]"`
```

I simply want a way of checking if `s` contains `"_2"` in the first position. In other words, after the first `_` symbol, is the single number a "2"? How do I do this in R?

I'm assuming I need some complicated regex expresion?

Examples:

```
39820432_2_349802j_32hfh = TRUE
```

`43lda821_9_428fj_2f = FALSE` (notice there is a `_2` there, but not in the right spot)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
> grepl("^[^_]+_1",s)
[1] FALSE
> grepl("^[^_]+_2",s)
[1] TRUE
```

basically, look for everything at the beginning except `_`, and then the `_2`.

+1 to @Ananda_Mahto for suggesting `grepl` instead of `grep`.

Comment: Is there a general solution? One that works when I don't know the string I'm searching for ahead of time, and allows it to have regexp characters inside of it?

Comment: NVM, I figured it out use `fixed=TRUE` option with `grepl`, your answer is good, OP's title is misleading.

Answer (score 30):

I think it's worth answering the generic question "R - test if string contains string" here.

For that, use the 
grep function.

```
# example:
> if(length(grep("ab","aacd"))>0) print("found") else print("Not found")
[1] "Not found"
> if(length(grep("ab","abcd"))>0) print("found") else print("Not found")
[1] "found"
```

Comment: more elegant: `if(grepl("ab", "aacabd")) print("found") else print("not found")`

Comment: `ifelse(grepl("ab", "aacabd"), "found", "not found")`

Comment: Or to make the output of any further use:

`ifelse(grepl("ab", "aacabd"), TRUE, FALSE)`
or
`ifelse(grepl("ab", "aacabd"), 1, 0)`